# Horizontally centering and spacing with css

Tags: css

I want to produce an image gallery style page for a responsive web site.
Depending on device and orientation the page displays between 1 and 4 images horizontally.

How can I achieve this and ensure that:

1. The space between the images remains equal
2. Each row is centered on the page regardless of device,
   orientation and the number of images.

I would appreciate any pointers, as I am new to this I may have overlooked the correct terminology while attempting to find the answer using the search feature.
Thanks for your time and consideration.

```
#verwrapper {
  text-align:left;
  width:100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top:20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  text-align:center; /* for IE */ 
} 

.ver{
  position:relative;
  border-bottom:2px solid #686868;
  width:200px;
  height:310px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 0.5em;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
}

.verbild{
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  outline:2px solid #C0C0C0;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

<div id="verwrapper">
  <div class="ver">
    <div class="verbild"><img src="image1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ver">
    <div class="verbild"><img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ver">
    <div class="verbild"><img src="image3.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nick

Comment: Wh@t h@ve you done so far? Any code? What do you want?

Comment: May be this would help you? [Responsive Image Gallery](http://bit.ly/1wxYhjZ).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a Gallery plugin, I just described it as a gallery to descibe what I need. I will post the code I have, perhaps that makes it clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use same padding for right & left side(em or %), use `margin:0 auto`. like that -

```
.test1{
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:0 0.5em;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although the spacing is correct, I still have everything on the left of the screen :-(
I will post the code that I have tried so far.

Comment: I think, you need to specify width(10%,5% or any amount preferable for your content).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just change sizes as you need.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .row {width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;}
  .image {width: 25%; float: left;box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0 5px;}
  .image img { width: 100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: I really thought that was going to do it!
Problem is that it is always going to try to display 4 images in a row. Great on a desktop PC but for a tablet in portrait orientation it should only display 2 or maybe 3 images per row and for a cell phone in portrait just 1 image per row.

Comment: you have to use media queries to manipulate between different resolutions.

check this link.. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Great link! I think I see the light. Thanks!!